# Why is AWS Gateway setting the wrong content length for an image streamed from S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless

Using the out the box Serverless template for C# .Net Core 2.0, I've created an S3 bucket that contains an image - I want to display this in a browser.

Running the webapi locally I can view the image fine and the content-length header isn't even included. When accessing via https://apidemo.boro2g.co.uk/media/mirrored-faces.jpg the content-length is getting changed to be bigger than it should. The original image is roughly 300kb but out of the API gateway its roughly 400kb.

I want to use the proxy to apply some custom security over the images so don't want them to be public, for testing you can see the original at https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/boro2g-photogallery/mirrored-faces.jpg

I've tried adding the binary media types as well within the API but these don't seem to have any effect.

The code to 'get' the image is pretty simple:

```
[HttpGet("{key}")]
    public async Task Get(string key)
    {
        try
        {
            var getResponse = await S3Client.GetObjectAsync(new GetObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = BucketName,
                Key = key
            });

            Response.ContentType = getResponse.Headers.ContentType;

            getResponse.ResponseStream.CopyTo(Response.Body);
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)e.StatusCode;
            var writer = new StreamWriter(Response.Body);
            writer.Write(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Why would the API be updating the **content-length** incorrectly?

FYI static txt files load without problem: https://apidemo.boro2g.co.uk/media/test.txt

Comment: Pulling down your object with a REST client confirmed my suspicion -- the payload is still base64 encoded, which I suspected because base64 encodes 6 bits per byte, expanding the size in a 4:3 ratio.  The content length is technically correct, because the object is indeed larger because it isn't being decoded from the intermediate base64 representation used between Lambda and API Gateway for binary payload.  The question, of course, is *why?*

Comment: It seems like I remember setting `*/*` as a binary content type in API Gateway as the workaround for this.  It seems wrong, but for some reason, I don't think the content type in this context refers to the *response* content type, in a sense as strict as you would expect, but rather to the content types in the user-agent's `Accept` request header.

Comment: Yes, I believe that is right... see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-workflow.html

Answer (score 4):

In the end the solution I found to work was:

1. In the settings for your api gateway, add the Binary Media Type: ***/***
2. On the **{proxy+}** method ‘Method Response’ add a **200** response header and add a header **Content-Type**. Finally publish your api

The second step here may not be necessary but I found the */* didn’t kick in until I made the change.

Comment: +1, especially on the binary media type. I tried "image/*", "image/jpg", etc and all didn't work but "*/*" did. Strange why that is...

Comment: Just deploying the gateway from the console will suffice to return the correct length after adding the Binary Media Type

Answer (score 1):

- In the api gateway settings, add */* (or the exact content types) to the Binary Media Type
- Click the "Deploy API" button (didn't work without it)
- I had to wait couple of minutes

Answer (score 0):

> Why is AWS Gateway setting the wrong content length for an image
> streamed from S3?

Your API Gateway is not rendering the binary data properly, its assuming the data is string in a different encoding such as base64, following did fix the issue.

API Settings > Binary Media Types
`*/*`

API Method Response, Add HTTP Status 200, and set desired Content-Type header

[image: check screenshot]

I also had to apply following patch for the response body to be converted to binary.

```
aws apigateway update-integration-response \
    --profile AWS_PROFILE_NAME \
    --rest-api-id API_ID \
    --resource-id RESOURCE_ID \
    --region AWS_REGION \
    --http-method GET \
    --status-code 200 \
    --patch-operations '[{"op" : "replace", "path" : "/contentHandling", "value" : "CONVERT_TO_BINARY"}]'
```